# Undefined error in accessing results from url

Tags: php, json, imdb

I'm making ajax call to search movies using the imdb api and I noticed for queries with spaces I get error; `Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp\www\..` for some of the results. How can I fix this?

```
($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
 $id = $row['imdb_id'];

 $test = "http://imdbapi.org/?id=tt00".$id."&type=json&plot=simple&episode=1&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0";   
 $cont = file_get_contents ($test);
 $data = json_decode($cont, true);   
 $title = $data['title'];    
 echo "$title";
```

Comment: Did you properly `urlencode` those spaces? By the way, that's not called an AJAX request.

Comment: Please show your database structure. `$id` is undefined.

Comment: First `var_dump($row)`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: what spaces? Also setting `$id=4;` outputs something.

Comment: @DaveChen: "I noticed for queries with spaces I get error"

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I actually call a db from the php, and then use the result to call the imdb api. Each time I type single queries, it works fine but queries having more than one word gives error in some of the results

Comment: Where are those queries coming from, you're talking about? First you say from database, then you speak about typing single queries: your code doesn't show so.

Comment: How many rows your `$sql` query returns? Don't you think that `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` returns 2 or more rows as a result and thus `$id` has to be something like `$id = $row[0]['imdb_id'];`? Sorry if I miss something, didn't use `mysql_*` for a long time

Answer (score 1):

This code is fairly working for me, (tested at my local server)

```
<?php

$row = array('imdb_id'=> 4);
//print_r($row);
 $id = $row['imdb_id'];

 $test = "http://imdbapi.org/?id=tt00".$id."&type=json&plot=simple&episode=1&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0";   
 $cont = file_get_contents ($test);
 $data = json_decode($cont, true);   
 $title = $data['title'];    
 echo "$title";
```

**Output** - Un bon bock

Remove `(` and `)` [Thanks to Marcel] from this line -

```
($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
```

To `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel yeah sure ..ie why I explicitly mentioned it in the below line :)